# how to specify Paypal Digitial / Virtual goods in checkout

Tags: paypal, virtual

I have a webform for paypal payment with a bunch of input type=hidden. My form begins with --form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"

how do i specify that the item is virtual goods? is there a variable to set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Payments Standard supports it technically.  You would need to use Payments Pro or Express Checkout, and then you would use the L_PAYMENTREQUEST_n_ITEMCATEGORYm parameter, where n is the payments number starting with 0 and m is the item number starting with 0.

So, you could have multiple payments on a single transaction, each with one or more items, and any or all of those items could be set as digital goods items.

See the [Express Checkout Digital Goods documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntroducingExpressCheckoutDG/) for more details.

If you're working with PHP then my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make the Express Checkout integration very simple for you.